# Apache virtual host set up for remote access

Tags: apache

I set up a virtual host on computer A by doing this:

Open apache config file (httpd.conf), insert lines as below:

> ```
> <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
>
> <Directory "{$path}/www/design-report/public/">
>   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>   AllowOverride FileInfo
>   Order deny,allow
>   Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ServerName weeklyreport.abc.com
> ServerAlias www.weeklyreport.abc.com 127.0.0.1
> DocumentRoot "{$path}/www/design-report/public/"
>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Then I added a line as below to system32/drivers/etc/hosts:

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 weeklyreport.abc.com
> ```

By now on computer A I'm able to access weeklyreport.abc.com just into the right folder. I want to access this address from another computer named B.

So I changed the hosts file on B by adding A's IP like this:

> ```
> 192.xxx.5.xx weeklyreport.abc.com
> ```

Now I can access weeklyreport.abc.com from computer B.

But the problem is, it isn't the right folder. By this IP I can only access {$path}/www, not "{$path}/www/design-report/public/".

How can I fix this? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Try changing your `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` to be `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Answer (score 1):

You missed the fact that VirtualHost definition tells apache to make virtual host only on given IP. It doesn't match for the external IP. You either need to defined second virtual host or use NameVirtualHost. For more details see [Apache docu](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)

HTH,Jan